# django rest framework import csv thorws requried Id error

Tags: ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to import CSV for existing table in database. For this I am using django-rest-framework-csv app. Event though, I am passing all the required data through javascript, but am getting  bellow error

**OrderedDict([('id', [u'This field is required.'])])**

CSV format

```
    address,city,id,zip
    sa,italy,4,99999
    sa,italy,5,8989
   sa,italy,6,99999
   sa,italy,7,8989
```

Please have a look at the Modelviewset,Serilizer and Model for more details

```
class AdressCSVViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""ViewSet for the Adress class"""

queryset = Adress.objects.all()
serializer_class = AdressCSVSerializer
parser_classes = (CSVParser,) + tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES)
renderer_classes = (CSVRenderer,) + tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES)
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


def get_renderer_context(self):
    context = super(AdressCSVViewSet, self).get_renderer_context()
    context['header'] = (
        self.request.GET['fields'].split(',')
        if 'fields' in self.request.GET else None)
    return context

@list_route(methods=['POST'])
def bulk_upload(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)


class CSVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
     model = Adress
     fields = (

        'id',
        'address',
        'city',
        'zip'
     )

class Adress(models.Model):
    # Fields
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    address = CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    city = CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

Request Data:

```
  [{u'city': u'italy', u'id': u'4', u'zip': u'99999', u'address': u'sa'}, {u'city': u'italy', u'id': u'5', u'zip': u'8989', u'address': u'sa'}, {u'city': u'italy', u'id': u'6', u'zip': u'99999', u'address': u'sa'}, {u'city': u'italy', u'id': u'7', u'zip': u'8989', u'address': u'sa'}]
```

Comment: what does the request.data look like ?

Comment: @Linovia it has orderRows

Comment: I have no idea what it is. Can you print request.data and join it to the question ?

Comment: @Linovia updated question with request data